# Java последовательность чисел

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!
Задание: дана последовательность чисел.Написать функцию,которая вернет наибольшую подпоследовательность знаков,которые расположены рядом друг с другом.Например если у нас есть 111223333455566666666666,то должно вернуть 66666666666.
Написала функцию и не понимаю,почему не работает...

```
public static String poslCast(int[]pole){
      String povtor="";
      String povtorNov;
       for(int i=0;i<pole.length-1;i++){
           povtorNov="";
          for(int j=0;j<pole.length-1;j++){
                if(pole[j]==pole[j+1]){
                    povtorNov+=pole[j];
                }
                else{
                    povtorNov+=pole[j-1];
                     if(povtorNov.length()>povtor.length()){
                povtor=povtorNov;   
            }
                     break;
                }  
          }
       }
       return povtor;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

У Вас алгоритм в корне неверный, задача решается за один проход массива, а не за N+1, где N - длина массива.

1. Введите длину максимального совпадения `maxlen`, изначально она равна нулю
2. Возьмите первый элемент массива, длину совпадения `currentlen` приравняйте единице
3. Сдвиньтесь на следующий элемент массива
4. Если он равен предыдущему элементу, то увеличьте `currentlen` на 1, вернитесь к шагу 3
5. Если он не равен предыдущему элементу, то проверьте больше ли `currentlen`, чем maxlen
6. Если больше, то поместите в `maxlen` значение `currentlen`, а в `maxsymbol` значение предыдущего символа
7. Приравняйте `currentlen` к 1, повторяйте шаг 3, пока не переберете весь массив
8. Верните строку из `maxlen` символов maxsymbol

Алгоритм выглядит как-то так.

Answer (score 2):

Вот весь пример целиком с проверкой, если я правильно понял задачу:

```
public class Povtor {

    public static String poslCast(int[] pole) {
        String longest_sequence = "" + pole[0], current_sequence = "" + pole[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < pole.length - 1; i++) {

            if(pole[i] == pole[i+1]) {
                current_sequence += pole[i];
                continue;
            }

            if(longest_sequence.length() < current_sequence.length()) {
                longest_sequence = current_sequence;
            }
            current_sequence = "" + pole[i + 1];

        }

        if(longest_sequence.length() < current_sequence.length()) {
            longest_sequence = current_sequence;
        }

        return longest_sequence;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(poslCast(new int[] {1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6}));
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! все поняла